# VBA- Autofill from the old last row to new last row in the same column

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to find the last row in column A and enter new value in next row.

```
  Dim l As Long

  l = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  ActiveSheet.Cells(l, "A").Value = "Your Value here"
```

But after that I need a code to find the last row in adjacent column and autofill until the last row.

Can some one please help me with the code?

Regards,
Karthick

Comment: Im not sure what do you want to do exactly. Tho, I can try to help you. Use this code-line to find the last row on a column `LastRow1 =.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` the 2 argument is to specify which column you are refering. If you can give a more clear example of what you want I will continue coding.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you mean?

```
LastRow1 =.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(lastRow1 + 1, 1).Value = "Your value here"

LastRow2 =.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & LastRow1 & ".AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow1 & ":A" & LastRow2 & "), Type:=xlFillDefault
```